# sed match multiple lines and then append

Tags: sed

I want to append some code after a verilog port list, which has the form:

```
module module_name (
input wire in1,
input wire in2,
output wire out1
);
```

I'm looking for help on how to use sed (or another command) to find the port list starting with "module" and ending with ");" and then append some code on the line following ");"

The command:

```
sed '/^module/,/);/a code to append' test.v
```

puts "code to append" on every line within the matched sequence and not only after it

```
module module_name (
code to append
input wire in1,
code to append
input wire in2,
code to append
output wire out1
code to append
);
code to append
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^module/,/);/!b;/);/a\NEWCODE' file
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Had been trying to match a particular C++ function and add a new function after. `sed '/SOME_C_FUNCTION()$/,/^}/!b;/^}/a TO_BE_CONTINUED...' source.cc`

Comment: @Kejml any lines not between a line starting with `module` and a line containing `);` are printed as normal. Otherwise `NEWCODE` is appended to a line containing `);`.

Comment: I see what does it do and I was able to adapt in to my case, so thanks for that. But I'm curious why, because I'm quite new to sed and it's syntax.

Comment: @Kejml The `/start/,/end/` focuses on a range of lines between and including `start` and `end`. The `!` negates that range i.e. not between `start` and `end`. The `b` command is like goto but by itself breaks out of the current commands. The `/);` focuses on any line that contains `);`. Finally, the `a` appends what follows on a new line following the current line i.e. `NEWCODE`. HTH

Answer (score 1):

This is a little kludgey, but it'll do the job:

```
sed ':a /module/s/);/);\ncode to append/;t;N;b a' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sed you can use command-line `perl` like this:

```
perl -0pe 's@(module[^(]*\([^)]*\)\s*;)@$1'"\na code to append"'@' test.v
```

#### OUTPUT

```
module module_name (
input wire in1,
input wire in2,
output wire out1
);
a code to append
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said sed or any other command I'll answer with perl. You can do this in perl with the following:

```
# perl -pe 'BEGIN { $/ = undef; }s#(^module.+?\);)#$1\ncode to append#omgs' test.v

module module_name (
input wire in1,
input wire in2,
output wire out1
);
code to append
```