# sed need something like a backreference for append

Tags: regex, sed

I have a whole bunch of C++ source files within which I wish to insert a trivial function definition (around 6 lines). The definition should appear immediately after another function definition.

Using the accepted answer to this question: [sed match multiple lines and then append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524888/sed-match-multiple-lines-and-then-append), I can insert the trivial function definition, but I am unable to scope it as a member of the appropriate class.

Test code:

```
void object::func1()
{
    std::cout << "func1" << std::endl;
}
```

Insertion of non-member function:

```
james@scrapyard:~/Projects$ sed  '/func1()$/,/^}/!b;/^}/a \\nint func2()\n{\n\ \ \ \ return 0;\n}' func1.cc 
void object::func1()
{
    std::cout << "func1" << std::endl;
}

int 1::func2()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Attempting to group the class name and use a back reference as below results in `1::func2` rather than `object::func2`.

`sed  '/\([[:alnum:]]\+\)::func1()$/,/^}/!b;/^}/a \\nint \1::func2()\n{\n\ \ \ \ return 0;\n}' testcode.cc`

If I were using the substitute command instead of the append command it would work, but the substitute command is broken by the `/,/` resulting in:

`sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown option to`s'`

Is it possible in sed?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, but `,` doesn't break anything. On the contrary, you must escape all litteral slashes: `\/,\/`

Comment: Trying to insert one method after another in a C++ source file, and additionally attempting to capture the C++ class name from the first method to scope the second method with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A backreference may only refer to a capture within the same expression.  The semicolon after `!b` ends the first expression. The hold space can carry a string from one expression to another.

`sed '/\w\+::func1()$/,/^}/!b;/\w\+::func1()$/{h;s/^\w*\s\+\(\w\+\)::func1()$/\1/;x};/^}/ {g;s/.*/}\n\nint &::func2()\n{\n\ \ \ \ return 0;\n}/}' testcode.cc`

Sed reads a line at a time into the pattern space, where commands like `s///` operate.
Lines can be set aside in the hold space and retrieved back into the pattern space later.

```
sed '
  /\w\+::func1()$/,/^}/!b   # Ignore lines outside the target function.
  /\w\+::func1()$/ {        # On the line declaring the function,
    h                       # save that line to the hold space;
    s/^\w*\s\+\(\w\+\)::func1()$/\1/  # replace the function with its class name;
    x                       # save the class name and restore the function declaration.
  }
  /^}/ {                    # at the end of the target function
    g                       # retrieve the class name
    # substitue the class name into the new function
    s/.*/}\n\nint &::func2()\n{\n\ \ \ \ return 0;\n}/
  }
' testcode.cc
```

Comment: Could you provide a brief breakdown please?

Comment: I added an explanation, but for the record, potong's solution is cleaner and simpler.  I was unaware that `//` reuses the most recent regex.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've been a little confused over the !b, thinking it had to do with jumping to a label... But it's regex for word boundary.. right?.. So not word boundary... is anything? .* ?

Comment: The `!` inverts the match, so `b` happens only when the regex (or range, or substitution) does _not_ match. The `b` without a label branches to the end of the script, effectively ignoring the current line. The word boundary pattern is `\b`.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^.* \([^:]*::\)func1()$/{h;x;s//\nint \1func2()\n{\n    return 0;\n}/;x};//,/^}$/{/^}$/G}' file
```

This looks for the function definition and then builds the trivial function in the hold space (HS). On encountering the end of the function it appends the HS.

Comment: pure niggle, but what's the `x` in `h;x` do?

Comment: @jthill the `x` command swaps the pattern space for the hold space. The `h` command copies the pattern space to the hold space. So `h;x;....;x` makes a copy of the cuttent line, swaps over to it, does whatever... and then swaps back to the current line leaving the changes made in the hold space. Later `G` command appends the hold space to the pattern space.

Answer (score 0):

The core of the question seems to be answered by this line in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-back_002dreference):

> Back-references and subexpressions are used in two cases: in the
> regular expression search pattern, and in the replacement part of the
> s command

which is to say that backreferences are not compatible with the append (`a`) command.